# Making parallel requests in spring boot

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-mvc

I am trying to build a simple service in Spring boot.

Step 1: To begin with, I have a list of customerIds. For example, [1,2,3,4,5...] etc.

Step 2: There is a service(service1) which gives me the book Ids associated with these customers. So i want to call over all customer Ids in parallel to get their book Ids.

Step 3: After i get the book IDs for each customer(which will be a list), i call two other services parallely to get book author(service2) and book image name(service3) for each book ID

Step 4: Just output the result in a JAVA POJO `List<Result>` with `Result` structure as

```
class Result{
    String userId;
    List<BookDetail>bookDetails
}
```

**What i have tried**

1. To get the book Ids paralley

```
Flux<String[]>bookIds=Flux.fromIterable(userIds)
                .flatMap(BoookListService::getBookIdsForUser);
```

2. To make parallel calls to service 2 and service 3, i [tried this method](https://www.amitph.com/spring-webclient-concurrent-calls/#simultaneous_webclient_calls_to_fetch_and_zip_different_types) and it worked, but that uses map and goes over the array sequentially. What i am trying to do is this

```
String testIds[]=list1.get(0);

Flux.fromArray(testIds)
       .flatMap(id->{

        })
       //.ordered((o1, o2) -> (int) (o1.compareTo(o2)))
       .toStream()
       .forEach(d -> System.out.println(d.toString()));
```

I want to make parallel calls to service 2 and service 3 together with the flatMap and then combine the result in my `List<Result>` object. Is there a way to make parellel calls like this and chain the results together?

Comment: What does `BoookListService::getBookIdsForUser` return?

Comment: You cannot combine results in List as it will block concurrent stream. The best is to have all data in Spring Flux, so Ids should be fetched as Flux<String>, not an array. Try to make your services asynchronous and, if you use WebFlux, return asynchronous response. If you want to block stream, you can use `.zip()` method or just run call of service3 in `.flatMap()` then use blocking `.toIterable()`